# How to force push node modules to GitHub

Tags: git, github, npm, node-modules, gitignore

I would like to include node modules in my git repository.
I know that it is most often recommanded **not** to include them (like explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50701496/why-can-not-i-upload-the-node-modules-file-into-github-repository) and in many other places) but :

- I want to check the module updates (and if they are safe) before delivering them to a client
- I don't want the project to depend on the possible removal of these modules
- they are tiny modules (100kb in all), so the argument on module's size do not stand

It seems that something in git is automatically preventing node modules to be added/commited/pushed. At least, they are not blacklisted by my `.gitignore`.

Could someone explain what exactly is preventing me to add them, and if it is possible to force the add ?

Answer (score 1):

**Please don't do this!**

> I want to check the module updates (and if they are safe) before
> delivering them to a client

- Use `npm audit` to check for safety and vulnerability.

> I don't want the project to depend on the possible removal of these
> modules

- Modules are never unpublished unless they are a legitimate security concern, almost entirely all deprecated packages are still kept available to ensure that they don't balls up projects (dependents) that rely on it. more here - https://www.npmjs.com/policies/unpublish

> they are tiny modules (100kb in all), so the argument on module's size do not stand

- I understand it's minuscule, however, if ever you need to scale up then you will have to download this small amount in a lot of environments and it all adds up.

Comment: Thanks for your advices, I did learn things here (like npm audit). I upvoted your answer for that. That said, both my questions are left unanswered. And I do not share your opinion about the eternal life of anything-code, like npm modules. Life tended to prove me the opposite. :)

Comment: I've updated the answer with some more info on criteria for publishing to demonstrate how unlikely it is to unpublish a package. :)

Comment: Thanks for you valuable information. Still not the answer to my question, which is not "should I do that", but "why is it so" and "how to do that" ? :)

Comment: I believe an answer that encourages best practice is more valuable 

Comment: What you consider a "best practice" is not necessarily true for every situation or person, but a mere organizational strategy that just happens to work for you (and hopefully, in most cases). I do appreciate your feedback though and think it is valuable, but please do consider situations that are outside the scope of what you consider best.

Comment: It is definitely best practice for npm, the fundamental idea of it is to provide instructions through package.json to other machines to download those packages without them being passed around. If you don't want to do that, it is absolutely fine :) If this is the case, don't use npm and download the packages directly into a downloads folder, or use a CDN.

Comment: Alright, your last comment gave me the answer : it seems [apple?]-git is automatically ignoring any "node_modules" folder, without any .gitignore file for that. I noticed this after renaming the "node_modules" folder by some other name and seeing the files appearing in the "Changes not staged" of my git status. I couldn't find any confirmation for this anywhere on the web, but it does happen here. So, for anyone who would need to do so, just rename the folder... Thanks @MaximillionBartango

Answer (score 0):

Check first if they are blacklisted by any other global setting than your .gitignore:

```
cd /path/to/my/repo
git check-ignore -v my_node_module/aFile_inside_node_module
```

Only then will you be sure there is no rule excluding your files.
See also if those modules are part of a nested git (look for any hidden `.git` folders)

Comment: Thanks for your help! I did upvote this.  Now, I get no response from the git check-ignore, so this is still and there are no hidden git repo. So I guess there is another reason elsewhere... that is left unanswered.

Comment: @Vincent Did you try a `git add --force my_node_module/aFile_inside_node_module`?

Comment: @Vincent Do you have a `.gitmodules` file in your repository?

Comment: I tried to force push the node_module folder, but I ended up with only Apple's `.DS_store` files showing up as staged files. I do not have any `.gitignore`file in my repo.